# How to create & access partitions of a dataset?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I am partitioning a dataset according to conditions; to partition a dataset for now, i am just creating seperate datasets through filtering like so :

```
        Dataset<Row> firstDf = df1.where("col2Att <= val1");
       
        Dataset<Row> secondDf = df1.where("col2Att > val2");
```

But i want to perform that within the dataset (without having to yield two datasets), and i was thinking it was possible through `partitionBy`. `val1` & `val2` are subject to update, and i want to partition a partition with other values than `val1` & `val2` (e.g `val3` & `val4`) all within the initial `df1` dataset in order for me to access each partition later on individually.

How to achieve that using Spark / Java ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean by `val1 & val2 are subject to update, and i want to partition a partition with other values than val1 & val2 (e.g val3 & val4)`. If I get this correctly, you want to have partitions in `df1` based on its `col2Att` column by checking its value with `val1`, `val2`. If you change `val1`, `val2`, then how will the partitions be formed? Maybe some rows from your input dataset and a desired output would clear things a bit more.

Comment: I want to partition the dataset over one attribute using more than just 2 values, and then i want to access each of the partition through the dataset.